# JavaScript `if` with multiple statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why the top piece of code works and the bottom one does not?

This one works:

```
var i=1
function next() {
    document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    if (i<jsArray.length-2) 
        i++
    else
        i=0
}
```

This one does not work:

```
var i=1
function next() {
    if (i<jsArray.length-2) 
        i++
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    else
        i=0
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
}
```

Comment: to avoid this problem in the future always place curly braces around your `if` and `else` statements. It never can hurt and all it adds are two characters.

Comment: Also use semicolons, yes they are optional, but best practice to use them. Tools like JSLInt/JSHint will help out and can be added into most ides.

Comment: Thank you everyone fore the help and advise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want more than one statement following an `if` or `else` condition, you need to wrap them in a block:

```
function next() {
    if (i<jsArray.length-2) {
        i++
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    }
    else {
        i=0
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    }
}
```

Note that syntactically this is equivalent - the `if` statement is still followed by a single statement (a block statement).

[The grammar](http://es5.github.com/#x12.5) gives the full details:

> *IfStatement* :
>       `if (` *Expression* `)` *Statement* `else` *Statement*
>       `if (` *Expression* `)` *Statement*

This shows that an `if` statement can only be followed by a single statement.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was going to be something simple like that I just couldn't find out what,

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. Others have suggested using tools like http://jshint.com to validate your code. This is generally a good idea. Run the code in question through it and you'll get a few more hints that will help you to follow best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You must keep the block of code that needs to be executed if the condition is true in curly braces.

```
var i=1
function next() {
    if (i<jsArray.length-2)
    { 
        i++
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    }
    else
    {
        i=0
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need braces:

```
function next() {
    if (i<jsArray.length-2) {
        i++;
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    } else {
        i=0;
        document.getElementById("photo").src = "http://www.Example.com/images/" + jsArray[i];
    }
}
```

I have also chosen to add semicolons.

For JS errors/warnings, you may find JSLint helpful: http://www.jslint.com